# Why READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE shows after using TextField on flutter

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, stream, textfield

I'm confused why after using TextField in code READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is asked? It doesn't make sense.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: TextField(
    ));
  }
}

Restarted application in 1,263ms.
W/ClipData( 9295): Failure opening stream
W/ClipData( 9295): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/file/80323 from pid=9295, uid=10347 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

Comment: maybe you use some lib , which is required Storage Permission, or check your menifest